# Man command freezes computer for ~30 seconds

Tags: man

Every time I run man to access a manual page my entire computer freezes for about 30 seconds.
My MANPATH is "/Library/init/zsh/man:/opt/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/X11/man:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/share/man:/opt/local/man" and my man.conf file looks pretty standard.

When I run man -d man for debugging info I get this:

> Reading config file /private/etc/man.conf
>
> Looked whether there exists a message catalog man, but there is none
> (and for English messages none is needed)
>
> found man directory /usr/share/man
>
> found man directory /usr/local/share/man
>
> found man directory /usr/X11/man
>
> found manpath map /bin --> /usr/share/man
>
> found manpath map /sbin --> /usr/share/man
>
> found manpath map /usr/bin --> /usr/share/man
>
> found manpath map /usr/sbin --> /usr/share/man
>
> found manpath map /usr/local/bin --> /usr/local/share/man
>
> found manpath map /usr/local/sbin --> /usr/local/share/man
>
> found manpath map /usr/X11/bin --> /usr/X11/man
>
> found manpath map /usr/bin/X11 --> /usr/X11/man
>
> found manpath map /usr/bin/mh --> /usr/share/man
>
> using less -ise as pager
>
> using /usr/bin/less -is as browser
>
> using /bin/cat to dump HTML pages as textadding /Library/init/zsh/man to manpath
>
> adding /opt/local/share/man to manpath
>
> adding /usr/share/man to manpath
>
> adding /usr/local/share/man to manpath
>
> adding /usr/X11/man to manpath
>
> adding /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/share/man to manpath
>
> adding /opt/local/man to manpath
>
> no cat page stored because of nonstandard line length
>
> using default preprocessor sequence
>
> found tbl(1) directive
>
> not executing command:
> (cd '/usr/share/man' && (echo ".ll 16.1i"; echo ".nr LL 16.1i"; /usr/bin/gunzip -c '/usr/share/man/man1/man.1.gz') | /usr/bin/tbl | /usr/bin/groff -Wall -mtty-char -Tascii -mandoc -c | (less -ise || true))

The computer freezes after "adding /opt/local/man to manpath" and before "no cat page stored because of nonstandard line length", so that might be related to my issue. Unfortunately Googling the "no cat.." message doesn't return anything useful.

Recently I've upgraded to OS X 10.7 and switched from bash to zsh, so those might play into the issue as well. However, using bash as my shell I still have the same issue. Any ideas?

Comment: To narrow the problem down:  Does it work better if you remove '/opt/local/man' from MANPATH?